# Yii2 Перестали работать стили из web/assets после изменения basePath

Tags: yii2

Ситуация следующая:

Использую Basic шаблон. Необходимо было сделать ЧПУ на сайте и убрать из пути папку 'web'

В файле настроек /config/web.php задаю следующее:

```
'components' => [
        baseUrl => '',
```

Я получаю желаемый результат, из url убирается папка web, но в то же время перестает подключаться bootstrap.css из временных папок /web/assets/Хеш/bootstrap.css т.к. путь к файлу bootstrap.css в индексном файле теперь прописывается без начального 'web': /assets/Хеш/bootstrap.css

Вопрос: как задать путь к врменной папке /web/assets/Хеш для всего приложения?

Если дал не полную информацию по тому что требуется, поправьте меня.

Answer (score 2):

В целом нашел решение, возможно кому-то пригодится:

```
'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/web/assets',
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было так же: если работаете на Open Server, то надо в настройках выбрать -- см. скриншот. Просто выбрать, не куда ничего не вставлять, никуда не лазить.

---

PS апач без nginx!!!